# Ruby gsub not replacing newline character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, replace, gsub

I have this code

```
str = @universal_claim_form.errors.full_messages.join
        str.gsub('Patient Contact Information: Value', 'Patient phone number') if str =~ /Patient Contact Information/
        debugger
        str.gsub("\\n", "<br/>")
        debugger
        flash.now[:error] = "Form has errors and was unable to be submitted.<br/> " << str
```

the first gsub replaces an unwanted message and the second gsub it meant to replace all the newline characters with html line breaks

at the first debugger line `str = "PMP Validation failed. This happens when something you entered does not pass PMP specific validations.\\nPatient phone number: Value must be a 10 digit number"`

and at the second debugger the line hasn't changed

what's even more weird is that I did this in irb at the command line and it worked

```
2.1.1 :001 > s = 'test'
 => "test"
2.1.1 :002 > s
 => "test"
2.1.1 :003 > s += '\ntest'
 => "test\\ntest"
2.1.1 :004 > s.gsub('\\n', '<br/>')
 => "test<br/>test"
2.1.1 :005 >
```

Comment: `gsub` is non mutating which means it will just return a copy of `str` with the characters subbed out (you will see this if you just call `s` again in irb the new lines are back again). You can use the mutating version `gsub!` and it should work. Also with `gsub` I find special characters are more readable in a regex e.g. `str.gsub!(/\n/,'<br/>')`. Finally note `gsub!` will return `nil` if no substitutions are made and `str` will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

You can call [`gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) to mutate the string you are calling it on (instead of returning a new string).

The reason `gsub` "works" in irb is because it is outputting the result - irb does not do any assignment or mutation (beyond what one enters), e.g.

```
irb(main):001:0> foo = 4
=> 4
irb(main):002:0> foo + 6
=> 10
```

`foo` is getting assigned `4` so it outputs the result of that assignment, likewise with `foo + 6` it outputs the result but the value of `foo` is unchanged.

When you call `gsub` it returns a *new* string with the substitution(s), this is why you feel it "works" in irb (this is no different then it printing "4" above).